# english learning unscramble game - how to display picture of each unscrambled word

Tags: flash, actionscript

I'm currently working on a unscramble english learning game similar to this game:
http://englishflashgames.blogspot.ca/2011/06/scrambled-words.html

What I want to do differently is to show a picture of the unscrambled word every time. How should I go about doing this? I will be unscrambling names of 10 fruits.

Thank you for your help.

```
package
{
   import flash.display.MovieClip;
   import flash.display.SimpleButton;
   import flash.events.MouseEvent;

   public class Game extends MovieClip
   {

  public function Game()
  {
     words = new Array();
     words_backup = new Array();
     tileArray = new Array();
     targetArray = new Array();
     scramble_Array = new Array();
     unscramble_Array = new Array();

     animals_b = new Array("peach","apple","strawberry","melon","grapes","cherry","pineapple","tomato","banana","orange");

     super();
     addFrameScript(0,frame1);
  }

  public var inici:MovieClip;

  public var bt1:SimpleButton;

  public var color:MovieClip;

  var words:Array;

  var words_backup:Array;

  var rand1:int;

  var rand2:int;

  var i:int;

  var ii:int;

  var ques_num:int;

  var current_word:String;

  var user_ans:String;

  var tileArray:Array;

  var targetArray:Array;

  var scramble_Array:Array;

  var unscramble_Array:Array;

  var temp:String;

  var flag:Boolean;

  var checker:button_chk;

  var f1:feedback1;

  var f2:feedback2;

  var f3:feedback3;

  var pauser:Boolean;

  var randomnum:int;

  var animals_b:Array;

  public function startGame(param1:*, param2:*) : *
  {
     inici.visible = false;
     color.x = param2.x;
     color.y = param2.y;
     if(words.length > 0)
     {
        i = 0;
        while(i < tileArray.length)
        {
           removeChild(tileArray[i]);
           removeChild(targetArray[i]);
           i++;
        }
        tileArray = [];
        targetArray = [];
        scramble_Array = [];
        unscramble_Array = [];
     }
     words = param1.slice();
     words_backup = param1;
     getword();
     checker = new button_chk();
     addChild(checker);
     checker.x = 290;
     checker.y = 450;
     checker.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,check_answer);
  }

  public function getword() : *
  {
     trace(words);
     if(words.length <= 0)
     {
        words = words_backup.slice();
     }
     randomnum = Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length);
     current_word = words[randomnum].toUpperCase();
     words.splice(randomnum,1);
     setTiles(current_word.length);
     ques_num++;
  }

  public function setTiles(param1:*) : *
  {
     var _loc2_:Tile = null;
     var _loc3_:Placeholder = null;
     tileArray = [];
     i = 0;
     while(i < param1)
     {
        _loc2_ = new Tile();
        addChild(_loc2_);
        _loc2_.x = 350 - param1 * 25 + param1 % 2 * 25 + i * 50;
        _loc2_.y = 350;
        _loc2_.tag = i;
        _loc2_.original_posx = _loc2_.x;
        _loc2_.original_posy = _loc2_.y;
        tileArray[i] = _loc2_;
        _loc3_ = new Placeholder();
        addChild(_loc3_);
        _loc3_.x = 350 - param1 * 25 + param1 % 2 * 25 + i * 50;
        _loc3_.y = 400;
        targetArray[i] = _loc3_;
        i++;
     }
     scramble_word(param1);
  }

  public function scramble_word(param1:*) : *
  {
     i = 0;
     while(i < param1)
     {
        scramble_Array[i] = current_word.slice(i,i + 1);
        i++;
     }
     i = 0;
     while(i < 15)
     {
        rand1 = Math.ceil(Math.random() * param1) - 1;
        rand2 = Math.ceil(Math.random() * param1) - 1;
        temp = scramble_Array[rand1];
        scramble_Array[rand1] = scramble_Array[rand2];
        scramble_Array[rand2] = temp;
        i++;
     }
     if(current_word == scramble_Array.join(""))
     {
        trace(scramble_Array.join(""));
        scramble_Array.reverse();
     }
     i = 0;
     while(i < param1)
     {
        tileArray[i].letter.text = scramble_Array[i];
        i++;
     }
     addListeners(param1);
  }

  public function addListeners(param1:*) : *
  {
     i = 0;
     while(i < param1)
     {
        tileArray[i].mouseChildren = false;
        tileArray[i].buttonMode = true;
        tileArray[i].addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN,pickup);
        tileArray[i].addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP,drop);
        i++;
     }
  }

  public function pickup(param1:MouseEvent) : *
  {
     if(!pauser)
     {
        param1.target.startDrag(true);
        this.setChildIndex(MovieClip(param1.target),this.numChildren - 1);
     }
  }

  public function drop(param1:MouseEvent) : *
  {
     param1.target.stopDrag();
     flag = false;
     i = 0;
     while(i < targetArray.length)
     {
        if(targetArray[i].hitTestObject(param1.target))
        {
           param1.target.x = targetArray[i].x;
           param1.target.y = targetArray[i].y;
           flag = true;
        }
        i++;
     }
     i = 0;
     while(i < tileArray.length)
     {
        if((tileArray[i].hitTestObject(param1.target)) && !(tileArray[i] == param1.target))
        {
           flag = false;
        }
        i++;
     }
     if(!flag)
     {
        param1.target.x = param1.target.original_posx;
        param1.target.y = param1.target.original_posy;
     }
  }

  public function check_answer(param1:MouseEvent) : *
  {
     user_ans = "";
     i = 0;
     while(i < targetArray.length)
     {
        ii = 0;
        while(ii < tileArray.length)
        {
           if(tileArray[ii].x == targetArray[i].x && tileArray[ii].y == targetArray[i].y)
           {
              user_ans = user_ans + tileArray[ii].letter.text;
           }
           ii++;
        }
        i++;
     }
     trace("user_ans: " + user_ans);
     trace("jordi_ans: " + user_ans);
     trace("current_word: " + current_word);
     if(user_ans == current_word)
     {
        f1 = new feedback1();
        addChild(f1);
        f1.x = 0;
        f1.y = 0;
        pauser = true;
        f1.buttonMode = true;
        f1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,clear_board);
     }
     else
     {
        f2 = new feedback2();
        addChild(f2);
        f2.x = 0;
        f2.y = 0;
        pauser = true;
        f2.buttonMode = true;
        f2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,continue_on);
     }
  }

  public function continue_on(param1:MouseEvent) : *
  {
     f2.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,continue_on);
     removeChild(f2);
     pauser = false;
  }

  public function clear_board(param1:MouseEvent) : *
  {
     f1.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,continue_on);
     removeChild(f1);
     pauser = false;
     i = 0;
     while(i < tileArray.length)
     {
        removeChild(tileArray[i]);
        removeChild(targetArray[i]);
        i++;
     }
     tileArray = [];
     targetArray = [];
     scramble_Array = [];
     unscramble_Array = [];
     if(ques_num == words.length + 99999)
     {
        removeChild(checker);
        f3 = new feedback3();
        addChild(f3);
        f3.x = 0;
        f3.y = 0;
     }
     else
     {
        getword();
     }
  }

  function frame1() : *
  {
     bt1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,function():*
     {
        startGame(animals_b,bt1);
     });   
  }
   }
}
```

Comment: You can use an array to put your images (paths of external files or class names of images inserted in your library) as you did with fruits names.

Comment: Since each time, the word is called at random, how would I go about making sure that each displayed picture matches the corresponding word?

Comment: Images are ordered in the same order as words (fruits names) so when you pick a word, you know its index in the array, you have just to pick the image with the same index.

Comment: I'm sorry if I'm asking too much, but could you please show me exactly what lines to add? A lot of this code was decompiled and I'm actually doing this for my aunt who is an elementary teacher. I have movie clips (images) of each fruit in the library with AS linkages that are named after their corresponding fruit. Thank you so much nevertheless!

Comment: Try what I told and then you can put your code if you have some difficulties.